# Adding a string into a List in Groovy to iterate throws No such property: a for class: java.lang.String

Tags: groovy

I have string, which comes in as user's input. I am adding the String to an empty groovy List. The new List prints okay with the desired new content. But when I try to iterate over the new List, it spits an error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: java.lang.String
```

My test in the groovyConsole is as below:

```
def obj ="[a: 'files', b: 'filename', folder: [src: 'dir1', tgt: 'dir2']],[a: 'files2', b: 'filename2', folder: [src: 'dir3', tgt: 'dir4']]"

println obj.class.name //returns java.lang.String
//The empty List initialised
def l = []
println l.class.name
//Adds the string to the List l
l << obj
println l.class.name  //returns java.util.ArrayList as expected
//trying to iterate over the List l, as so throws the exception "No such property: a for class: java.lang.String"
l.each { k -> 
    println k.a
    println k.folder.src
}
```

note: `println l` , returns the below

```
[[a: 'files', b: 'filename', folder: [src: 'dir1', tgt: 'dir2']],[a: 'files2', b: 'filename2', folder: [src: 'dir3', tgt: 'dir4']]]
```

Comment: Can you get the user to input valid json?  Or something which is more easily parseable?

Answer (score 2):

It won't work this way. You can't refer to a `String` as if it was a `Map` or other object with property `a`. What you need to do is to define `obj` as a `Map` or define it as a `String` and evaluate using `Eval` for further processing. Below both examples work:

```
def obj = Eval.me("[[a: 'files', b: 'filename', folder: [src: 'dir1', tgt: 'dir2']],[a: 'files2', b: 'filename2', folder: [src: 'dir3', tgt: 'dir4']]]")

def l = []
l << obj

l.each { k -> 
    println k.a
    println k.folder.src
}

obj = [[a: 'files', b: 'filename', folder: [src: 'dir1', tgt: 'dir2']],[a: 'files2', b: 'filename2', folder: [src: 'dir3', tgt: 'dir4']]]
l.removeAll()
l << obj

l.each { k -> 
    println k.a
    println k.folder.src
}
```